# HTML5 Email Validation TLD without Pattern?

Tags: html, validation, email-validation

How do I tell my input to validate email inputs with the tld?

I don't want to accept email addresses in the form `a@b`.

I am aware I can specify a regex pattern to assert this behaviour, but this feels like a hacky approach. Is there a native attribute I can use to force the input element to validate the email address, **including** tld?

```html
<form>
    <input type="email" required="required" pattern="^[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+$" value="a@b" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: why don't you just take the inputted full email address (i.e. a@b.c) and parse out the bits you want to test?  If you wanted to validate, specifically the TLD, then you'd have to parse/split it out anyway

Comment: I'm also a little confused by your OP, sorry.  Do you want to validate the TLD only, or validate the TLD when the user enters a@b.c?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native attribute to validate the TLD. You can use the pattern attribute to validate the TLD though. I have the copy and paste code snippet here: https://github.com/coliff/html5-email-regex